# AzureDevOps clone and commit external repo

Tags: github, azure-devops

I have a azure devops pipeline which checkout a github repo , i also want to have a bash task to checkout another repo and modify it , check it back in .

```
git clone https://$(githubApiKey)@mygithub.private.com/myrepo/ops-one-code.git
```

**Error message:**

> fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@mygithub.private.com':
> terminal prompts disabled

Comment: Navigate on Azure Devops Repository -> press clone and then -> press generate git credentials.

Comment: This is not a azure repo but a external GitHub repo and I already have a external api key

Comment: You can create a service connection with your github organization/account and add the repository as a resource. this is the recommended way to go in order to checkout a github repository on azure devops.

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate personal access token on GitHub?

Just create new token from the below page with needed scopes:

> settings > developer settings > personal access tokens > generate new
> token

[image]

Then use git clone command like below:

```
git clone https://auth-token-goes-here@mygithub.private.com/myrepo/ops-one-code.git
```

Comment: https://$(githubapikey) is there which is passed a a secret . Yes I did already generate a personal token api key .

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your requested task using two powershell tasks:

Task to checkout a Github repository:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Checkout Repo
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      git config user.email "user.email"
      git config user.name "user.name"
      Remove-Item s1 -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
      git clone https://username:$(PAT)@github.com/org/repo.git s1
      cd s1
      git checkout main
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

Task to push back on the Github repository

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Push git changes
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      git config user.email "user.email"
      git config user.name "user.name"
      git add --all
      git commit -m "message"
      git push https://username:$(PAT)@github.com/org/repo.git s1
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the azure variable was a secret and it didn’t work with it hence it prompted for the password

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).